# Call function from Directive AngularJS

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am trying to call a function inside a directive. Here is a html:

```
<span class="delete-link">
    <delete></delete>
    <input type="button" data-ng-click="removeRow(task)"/>
</span>
```

And here is the directive:

```
.directive('delete', function() {
        return {
            restrict: 'E',
            replace: true,
            template: '<div></div>',
            link: function(scope, element) {
                element.click(function(){
                    $scope.removeRow = function (task) {
                        $scope.tasks.splice($scope.tasks.indexOf(task), 1);
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    });
```

This is the example I used:

http://jsfiddle.net/mrajcok/T96Zu/

But it doesn't delete an element. What I'm missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use scope instead of $scope

```
.directive('delete', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        replace: true,
        template: '<div></div>',
        link: function(scope, element) {
            element.click(function(){
                scope.removeRow = function (task) {
                    scope.tasks.splice(scope.tasks.indexOf(task), 1);
                }
            });
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

```
.directive('delete', function() {

      return {

            restrict: 'E',
            replace: true,
            template: '<div></div>',

            link: function(scope ,element) {

                    scope.removeRow = function (task) {
                        scope.tasks.splice(scope.tasks.indexOf(task), 1);
                    }

            }

        }

    });
```